# Apple (enterprise) developer programm: Same team agent of multiple teams seems not possible

Tags: ios

we as a company are enrolled in two developer programs of apple

- Apple Developer Program
- Apple Developer Enterprise Program

  Historically both programs were overseen by two different persons at my company, one of being myself for the Apple Developer Program.

Now we want to switch the team agent of the Apple Developer Enterprise Program also to me. However, this seems not possible, as the old agent gets the following error when trying to do so:

"The selected team agent is already an agent of another team. Please choose another member"

While this statement is fairly clear, I'd like to know...

1. if anybody has information why that should be so
2. if anybody of you succeeded in consolidating the two programs under one agent

Will open a support ticket to apple and report back here, of course. Just wanted to know, if I might be missing something :-)

Many thanks and kind regards
Jens

Comment: What's the reason for having both programs? Isn't the enterprise program a *superset* of the developer program? I thought you could migrate your developer program to enterprise program which would make a developer program obsolete... I'm asking because my company has the same set-up just as a few of our customers...

Comment: That is not true. Both programs serve different purposes. Developer Program for App Store (public) apps, Enterprise Developer Program for in-house apps

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Contacted Apple Support about this. Answer was to use alternate Apple ID.

So your best bet if you start from scratch would probably be to generate two distinct email addresses, one for each developer program like:

- adp@example.com
- adep@example.com

Create an according Apple ID for each and use that on the specific program.

Shame though, that you can't use the same Apple ID for the two programs.

Edit on May 2018: This is now (maybe has always been) at least to some extend part of the Apple enrollment documentation. https://developer.apple.com/support/enrollment/
It currently reads:

> Enrolling in Multiple Programs
>   The Apple Developer Enterprise Program and the iOS Developer University Program each require a unique Apple ID than that used for any other membership. You’ll need to set up a new Apple ID and enroll separately. If you currently have an iTunes Connect account to sell another media type (books, music, TV content, or movies), you cannot use the Apple ID associated with that iTunes Connect account to enroll in any other programs. You’ll need to set up a new Apple ID for all other memberships.

---

**Edit 2020/01/14:**
The current wording is slightly different, but still you'll need separate Apple IDs for ADP, AEDP and IDUP

> The Apple Developer Enterprise Program and the iOS Developer University Program each require separate identity verification. To enroll, you’ll need to set up a new Apple ID and go through our standard verification process.

Cheers
Jens

Comment: Thank you, it was helpful. I had the same issue currently.

Comment: I have the same issue now. We have 7 accounts. 2 live and 5 enterprise accounts. With the new security restrictions on apple ids its amazing that they force to create a ton of `fake` accounts. Also I can't use `name+subname@domain` email-addresses for creating the ids. So it means I need 7 real mail accounts to kick this off...

Comment: Its worse than that, they also require unique mobile phone numbers, so even if you get two real email addresses, you won't be able to get it to work (without purchasing another phone plan!!).