# How to add multiple teams to Xcode server? (Enterprise and Developer teams)

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration, xcode10, xcode-server

This is with Xcode 10.

I have 2 different Apple IDs associated with the same project. One is for the Enterprise Program, builds for distribution within the company. The other is for Developer Program builds, to be submitted to App Store. How can i add 2 teams (enterprise and release) to the xcode server?

e.g. This is the signing tab on the Edit Bot screen for one of the bots which generates a Enterprise Debug build. I would like to see 2 Developer Teams on this screen:

The one i currently see is only the Developer Program team in this.

[image]

Bonus related question: Has anyone been able to setup bots to achieve automatic code signing for release builds, while having both Enterprise and Developer programs? Is this even supported by Xcode server?
I currently get the following error from bot while building Enterprise Debug build:

`<Target> has conflicting provisioning settings. <Target> is automatically signed, but provisioning profile Enterprise Distribution has been manually specified. Set the provisioning profile value to "Automatic" in the build settings editor, or switch to manual signing in the project editor. (in target 'Target')`

Comment: I think your question was answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36353795/apple-enterprise-developer-programm-same-team-agent-of-multiple-teams-seems-n. <br>

Comment: @brunoportela Thanks for sharing. But, no, it was not answered in the question you shared. I specifically am trying to know how single instance of Xcode Server can be configured with automatic signing, with an Enterprise and Developer accounts. Seems like neither Apple, nor community has an answer for this. I have switched to manual signing for now. Thank you!